# Compiler Errors Adding AFNetwork to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking

I've looked at all the questions on StackOverflow regarding this, and nothing has helped. I followed this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk_afnetworking--mobile-10741) for setting up the AFNetworking library with xcode to use for my project, however I am getting this error in the AFURLSessionManager.m file:

```
Semantic Issue: @synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode
```

and a yellow caution sign for the same file:

```
Semantic Issue: Method possibly missing a [super dealloc] call
```

I'm very lost at this point since I'm fairly new to iOS development to begin with, and adding this framework has been nothing but frustration.

Comment: Does your project use ARC?

Comment: @WenchenHuang I never bothered to check, I just started coding with the default setting. Is it normally on or off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you don't use Cocoapods. With me that's the best one to import a library. Try and you will like it.

Comment: :D hope that you like it.